# Print house with n floor [C#]

Tags: c#, floor

I want to print a house with n floor on my console, how can i do it

```
public static void housefloor(int n)
    {
        Roof();
        Ground();

        if (n > 0)
        {
            Roof();
            Floor();
            Ground;
        }

    }
```

Comment: What is printing a house?

Comment: Bibi, it would be helpful if you gave more information about what you expect to output, exactly.  A clear description, or better yet an example of the expected output.

Comment: `if (n > 0) { ... Ground(); }`

Answer (score 0):

```
Roof();

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    Floor();
}

Ground();
```

Also
[this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/index.htm) and [this](http://csharp.net-tutorials.com/basics/introduction/)